# Same row different column (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

A table contains nicknames and IDs.

Given a nickname, I am looking up its ID.

However, my solution only works if the "ID" column is next to the "Nickname" column. The columns may change position in the future.

Therefore, how do I update my code so the column positions don't matter?

Note:  Column **names** will never change, only their positions might change.

```js
// Given a Nickname, lookup its ID. 


// Example of a nickname
let exampleN = "A";

// Find the <th> with the text "Nickname"
columnHeader = $("#table1 th:contains('Nickname')");

// Get the index & increment by 1 to match nth-child indexing
columnIndex = columnHeader.index() + 1;

// Loop through each element in that index...
$('#table1 tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').each(function() {


  if ($(this).text() === exampleN) { // if match is found...
    let ID = $(this).next().text(); // get the <td> next to that <td>
    alert("The ID for that nickname is " + ID);
    return false; // exits loop after condition is met
  } else {
    alert("No match was found for that nickname.");
    return false; // exits loop after condition is met
  }

})
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 11em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Nickname</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhpakr0c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to identify the column indices for "nickname" and "id".
Then you can reference those indices to map nicknames to ids.

```js
let exampleN = "C";

// Given a Nickname, lookup its ID. 

let colKey = $("#table1 th:contains('Nickname')").index();
let colVal = $("#table1 th:contains('ID')").index();
let id;

// Loop through each "nickname" cell ...
$('#table1 tr td:nth-child(' + (colKey + 1) + ')').each(function() {

  if ($(this).text() === exampleN) { // if match is found...
    // set id and end loop
    id = $(this).siblings('td').addBack().eq(colVal).text();
    return false;
  }

})

// if id was found, display it.
if (id) {
  console.log("The ID for " + exampleN + " is " + id);
} else {
  console.log("No match was found for that nickname.");
}
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 11em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Other></th>
    <th>Nickname</th>
    <th>Another</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>n/a</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you just want to associate ids with nicknames, or if you are performing multiple searches on the same table, you may want to consider building an array of all relevant table data. Then you can perform lookups using that array.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
// Search dataset by nickname and output id
function searchNicknames(data, search) {

  let match = data.filter(data => data.nickname == search);

  // If a match is found, display it
  if (match[0]) {
    console.log("The ID for " + match[0].nickname + " is " + match[0].id);
  } else {
    console.log("No match was found for " + search + ".");
  }

}


// Determine column indexes
let colKey = $("#table1 th:contains('Nickname')").index();
let colVal = $("#table1 th:contains('ID')").index();

// Build array of table data
let tableData = $('#table1 tr td:nth-child(' + (colKey + 1) + ')').map(function() {

  return {
    'nickname': $(this).text(),
    'id': $(this).siblings('td').addBack().eq(colVal).text()
  };

}).get();


// Search by nickname
searchNicknames(tableData, 'C');
searchNicknames(tableData, 'B');
searchNicknames(tableData, 'F');
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 11em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Other</th><th>Nickname</th><th>Another</th></tr>
  <tr> <td>1</td><td>n/a</td><td>A</td><td>n/a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>n/a</td><td>B</td><td>n/a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>n/a</td><td>C</td><td>n/a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>n/a</td><td>D</td><td>n/a</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Expanding on this: https://jsfiddle.net/b3wyc6uf/ . Suppose the nicknames are spread into 2 tables. We want to search the second table if we don't find it in the first table. Is there a better solution than copy pasting #table1 with #table2 and duplicating that code?